# how to create dynamic menu in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Interface like this:

```
export interface INavData {
    name?: string;
    url?: string | any[];
    icon?: string;
  
}
```

and I set data to this interface like this:

```
export const navItems: INavData[] = [
  {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Colors',
    url: '/Category/subcategory',
    icon: 'icon-drop'
  },
  {
    name: 'Typography',
    url: '/Category/category',
    icon: 'icon-user'
  }
}
```

I have a Menus table in database, with following columns:

1. Name
2. Url
3. Icon

I return this table data with API.
Now how to get data from API for this Interface?
can you help me?

Note:
I get data in Service like this:

```
export class myService {
  readonly BaseURI = 'http://localhost:542213/api';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 getMenus()
  {
    return this.http.get<Menus[]>(this.BaseURI + '/Menus');
  }
}
```

I want to get Name, Url, Icon Values dynamically from API what should I do?

Comment: So, you can subscribe to the `getMenus()` method as it is returning an observable which gives you menu data

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti how to get getMenus() data into MenuItems Interface ?

Comment: `get getMenus() data into MenuItems Interface` means? can you explain it better?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti  I set data to  navItems: INavData[] statically, Now how to set  navItems: INavData[] dynamically from API, Please see my question again, you will find navItems: INavData[] example more details

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti   I set values to navItems: INavData[] Statically now how to get these values from API, Please see navItems: INavData[] example in my question again

Comment: So, where did you place `export const navItems: INavData[] = [...]`? The component where you subscribed to the api call only right?

Answer (score 0):

you can get data from api into your .ts file using subscribe method like this...

**.ts**

```
 import {myService} from 'PRTH';

 constructor(private _myService: myService)

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getMenuData()
 }

getMenuData(){
   this._myService.getMenus().subscribe((res)=>{
    console.log(res);             <-- this is your api Data
 });
}
```

now you can get api data into your console....

Comment: yes I can get data into my ts file like your example, now how to set this data to menu items interface

Comment: How to get getMenus() data into navItems Interface???

Comment: you can set data that you get form api into your Interface

Comment: How to get getMenus() data into navItems Interface???, It was my Real Problems if you tell me this I want set your answer as correct Answer and also I will give +1

Comment: I set values to navItems: INavData[] Statically now how to get these values from API, Please see navItems: INavData[] example in my question again